# How do you get the Discriminated Union Type from a Case instance?

Tags: reflection, f#, discriminated-union

Given these two Discriminated Unions I'd like to get the `DeclaringType` from a case instance.

```
type SingleCaseUnion =
    | One

type MultiCaseUnion =
    | Two
    | Three
```

An example for each case would be as follows:

```
getDiscriminatedUnionType One = typeof<SingleCaseUnion> // true

getDiscriminatedUnionType Three = typeof<MultiCaseUnion> // true
```

---

My first attempt was to get the case type and get it's base class, this works because in F# a subtype is created for each case.

```
MultiCaseUnion.Two.GetType().BaseType = typeof<MultiCaseUnion> // true
```

However, for a single case union this doesn't work because no nested types are created.

```
SingleCaseUnion.One.GetType().BaseType = typeof<SingleCaseUnion> // false
```

---

My second attempt, which aimed to get a more robust solution was to use the FSharp Reflection helpers.

```
FSharpType.GetUnionCases(unionValue.GetType()).First().DeclaringType
```

This does work for all cases but it has to generate UnionCaseInfo instances for each case which seems somewhat unnecessary.

Is there Something built in that I may have missed? Something like:

```
FSharpValue.GetUnionFromCase(SingleCaseUnion.One)
```

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
open FSharp.Reflection
type FSharpType =
    static member GetUnionType t =         
        let ownType = t.GetType()
        assert FSharpType.IsUnion(ownType)
        let baseType = ownType.BaseType        
        if baseType = typeof<System.Object> then ownType else baseType
```

Test:

```
(FSharpType.GetUnionType MultiCaseUnion.Three).Name //MultiCaseUnion

(FSharpType.GetUnionType SingleCaseUnion.One).Name //SingleCaseUnion
```

Comment: It's probably the best solution at the moment. However, it doesn't require the type to be a Discriminated Union.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to constrain to a union type. Added as assertion though.